# PyPDF2 encoding issues

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf

I'm having some trouble identifying why the output doesn't match the input of the PDF when pulling the text. And if there are any tricks I could do to fix this as it's not an isolated issue.

```
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
  binary = PyPDF2.pdf.PdfFileReader(f)
  text = binary.getPage(x).extractText()
print(text)
```

file: "I/O filters, 292–293"
output: "I/O Þlters, 292Ð293"

The Ð seems to represent all instances of '-' and Þ seems to be used for all instances of "fi".

I am using Windows CMD as my output for testing and I do know some characters don't show up right, but that leaves me baffled for something like the 'fi'

Comment: `fl` = `ß`, `'` = `Õ`, and there are instances of odd spacing that exists in the output that do not exists in the input file. These are rare, about 10 for 20 pages sampled.

Answer (score 1):

The text extraction of PyPDF2 was massively improved in versions 2.x. The whole project moved to `pypdf`.

I recommend you give it another try: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-text.html

```
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")
page = reader.pages[0]
print(page.extract_text())
```

Comment: Just now seeing this. I'll try this again when I have a moment. Thanks Martin.